# angularjs TypeError: require(...) is not a function , nodejs run error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am implementing a very similar code as found [here](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Forms-Article/blob/master/web.js)

When I run node web.js, I get a **TypeError: require(...) is not a function**

 why should i get such an error? where is the problem?

here is my web.js

```
var express = require('express');

var apiFiles = './backend';
var wwwFiles = './app';

require(apiFiles + '/api')(function(backend) {
  var www = express.static(wwwFiles);
  express()
    .use('/api', backend)
    .use('/', www)
    .listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
```

and here is my folder structure:

[image]

The final aim is to deploy it to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing either `requireJS` or `express`.

Add this line right above your require statement- 
`console.log('require');`

If that passes in a function then just run `npm install --save express` (or `express@whatever-version-you-want`

Otherwise you may want to re-setup your app. I'm pretty sure requireJS is part of node's core.

Comment: what'd the console.log output? And can you include your package.json file in the question?

Comment: i included a more complete version of the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191704/angularjs-app-web-js-structure-to-deploy-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json, if you have "module" set to "system", try changing it to "commonjs" instead. That worked for me.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceRoot": "./client",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules",
        "../typings/main",
        "../typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```